# Concurrent file upload/download and running background processes

Tags: python, bash, concurrency, background-process

I want to create a minimal webpage where concurrent users can upload a file and I can process the file (which is expected to take some hours) and email back to the user later on.

Since I am hosting this on AWS, I was thinking of invoking some background process once I receive the file so that even if the user closes the browser window, the processing keeps taking place and I am able to send the results after few hours, all through some pre-written scripts.

Can you please help me with the logistics of how should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how it might look like (hosting-agnostic):

1. A user uploads a file on the web server
2. The file is saved in a **storage** that can be accessed later by the background jobs
3. Some metadata (location in the storage, user's email etc) about the file is saved in a **DB**/**message broker**
4. Background jobs tracking the **DB**/**message broker** pick up the metadata and start handling the file (this is why it needs to be accessible by it in p.2) and notify the user

More specifically, in case of `python`/`django` + `aws` you might use the following stack:

1. Lets assume you're using `python` + `django`
2. You can save the uploaded files in a **private** AWS `S3 bucket`
3. Some meta might be saved in the `db` or use `celery + AWS SQS` or `AWS SQS` directly or bring up something like `rabbitmq` or `redis`(+*pubsub*)
4. Have python code handling the job - depends on what your opt for in p.3. The only requirement is that it can pull data from your S3 bucket. After the job is done notify the user via `AWS SES`

The simplest single-server setup that doesn't require any intermediate components:

1. Your python script that simply saves the file in a folder and gives it a name like `someuser@yahoo.com-f9619ff-8b86-d011-b42d-00cf4fc964ff`
2. Cron job looking for any files in this folder that would handle found files and notify the user. Notice if you need multiple background jobs running in parallel you'll need to slightly complicate the scheme to avoid race conditions (i.e. rename the file being processed so that only a single job would handle it)

In a prod app you'll likely need something in between depending on your needs